# Difference between Create User and Grant Privileges in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a question related to passwords:

We can create a user and assign him a password by doing this:

```
CREATE USER Bobby IDENTIFIED BY 12345
```

Then we can also grant him permissions by doing:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO Bobby@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

However, when we change the password for that user by doing:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'Bobby'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpassword');
```

I am able to login with this new password, and also do any kind of queries to the databases. So, is it true that when updating the password, we are actually updating both the one created with `CREATE USER Bobby` and the one created with `GRANT`?

The other part of the question is... If the password used when CREATE is different than the password used when GRANT, it seems that the GRANT password takes priority. So, why would the password in CREATE be useful for?

Comment: Couldn't you answer this yourself with a quick test faster than you could type the question here?

Comment: @KenWhite I have updated the question, I am just confused about how it would be different if the password of CREAET USER is different than the password from GRANT?

Comment: As I said, can't you simply **try it**? If you create a test user, grant select to them, and then change their password and try to do a select again, it should answer your question. No? You can delete the test user afterward. (You can even create a small test database first to use, and delete it afterward.) You'd have an answer a lot more quickly it's taken so far (24 minutes as of now).

Comment: I have tried that. And after changing the password it lets me do the SELECT, so I am wondering than when updating it updates for all. I just want to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: Did you consider now trying to do an INSERT or UPDATE in order to find out? Sometimes it's good to not have to wait for others to tell you things, but to actually try things to teach yourself. I've learned several entire programming languages and a large amount of SQL by doing so. It can also be fun, sometimes. :-)

Comment: Ken White, I know what you are trying to say, but I have tried that. Notice that Bobby is grant ALL in ALL databases, so if I change the password it keeps letting me do SELECT, so I am assuming that actually changint the password affects in the password set in CREATE and also in the password set in GRANT. But I would like a confirmatino from somebody who knows more than me.

Comment: For Pete's sake. So create a test user and **don't GRANT ALL** and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens.

With this

```
CREATE USER 'Bobby' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

a user is created. He has no rights but to connect and look at how the server is configured and at some status variables. The same happens when you do this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'Bobby'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

You don't even need the `CREATE USER` statement before. The `GRANT` statement would create the user if it doesn't exist.
Because we specified a password with the `GRANT` statement, the password gets changed, too. There are no separate passwords or whatever.

When you change your password either via `GRANT` statement or via `SET PASSWORD`, you can only login with the new password.

While the privileges are checked for every query, the password isn't! When you don't disconnect, you can still execute all queries you have the rights for, although you connected with the old password.

**Edit:** I have to correct myself, the privileges are not checked for every query. The user has the rights he had when he connected as long as he is connected. When privileges are revoked from the user, he has to reconnect to really lose the privilege.

Comment: From the docs, When IDENTIFIED BY is present and you have the global grant privilege (GRANT OPTION), the password becomes the new password for the account, even if the account exists and already has a password. Without IDENTIFIED BY, the account password remains unchanged.

Comment: So? Have I said anything different?

Comment: Just adding that identified by is optional.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't want to be rude.